# .htaccess redirect all domains, with paths, to one

Tags: .htaccess, 301-redirect

I have three domains all pointing to the same hosting space, mirrored using `A` records:

- `example.org`
- `example.org.uk`
- `example.co.uk`

I have a website on the root (`/`), and a MediaWiki installation at `example.org/members/wiki`. I'd like all requests to redirect to HTTPS and to the `.org` domain.

I've managed this with the website using `.htaccess` in the root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !example.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but I can't get it to work with the wiki -- requests to the `.org.uk` or `.co.uk` domains are not redirected.

I have this `.htaccess` in `/members`:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^example.org.uk(/.*)?$     https://www.example.org/$1
RewriteRule ^example.co.uk(/.*)?$ https://www.example.org/$1 

# MediaWiki pretty URL rewrites
RewriteRule ^/?members/wiki(/.*)?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/members/wiki/index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/members/wiki/index.php [L]
```

I want, for example, `example.co.uk/members/wiki/My_Page` to seamlessly redirect to `https://www.example.org/members/wiki/My_Page`.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that mod_rewrite directives are not inherited by default. The mod_rewrite directives in your `/members/.htaccess` file are completely overriding the mod_rewrite directives in the parent `.htaccess` file. The mod_rewrite directives in the parent `.htaccess` file are not being executed when your wiki is accessed.

You can enable mod_rewrite inheritance from the `/members/.htaccess` file (using `RewriteOptions Inherit`), however, the current directives in the parent `.htaccess` file are still not going to work if they are inherited. (Directives are inherited as if they are literally copied into the subdirectories `.htaccess` file.)

To use mod_rewrite inheritance, you would need to change the following directives in the parent `.htaccess` file:

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteBase /
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !example.org$ [NC]
> RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.org/$1 [R=301,L]
> ```

to read:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !example\.org$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.org%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The `RewriteBase` directive is superfluous here. (Unless you have other directives?) The `REQUEST_URI` server variable contains the full URL-path, regardless of where is it used, unlike the captured URL-path from the `RewriteRule` *pattern* which notably has the directory prefix removed in a directory/`.htaccess` context. The `NC` flag should also be removed on this *negated CondPattern*, since you also want to redirect malformed requests.

*Aside:* However, this still doesn't canonicalise the www subdomain and nor will it redirect non-HTTPS requests to `example.org` - is this a requirement? For that you would need something like the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.org$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.org%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Note the start of string anchor (`^`) on the *CondPattern* (`!^example\.org$`). And the additional check against the `HTTPS` server variable (which is OR'd).

And then in `/members/.htaccess`, you replace the first part (which would never work anyway, since the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the URL-path only, not the hostname):

> ```
> Options -Indexes
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteRule ^example.org.uk(/.*)?$     https://www.example.org/$1
> RewriteRule ^example.co.uk(/.*)?$ https://www.example.org/$1
> ```

With the following:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions Inherit
```

---

Alternatively, you forget inheritance and simply copy the parent mod_rewrite directives into the `/members/.htaccess` file:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !example\.org$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.org%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

---

> ```
> # MediaWiki pretty URL rewrites
> RewriteRule ^/?members/wiki(/.*)?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/members/wiki/index.php [L]
> RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
> RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/members/wiki/index.php [L]
> ```

*Aside:* However, these directives would not work in a `/members/.htaccess` file either?! These directives are intended for the server config (or VirtualHost) context.

In per-directory `.htaccess` files, the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the URL-path *less the directory-prefix*. So, a pattern that starts `^/?members/` will never match when the `.htaccess` file itself is in the `/members` subdirectory. (However, this would work in a server/VirtualHost context since the *pattern* matches against the full URL-path.)

Also, in per-directory `.htaccess` files you cannot rewrite to an *absolute filesystem path*, it must be a document-root relative URL-path. (However, you could do this in a server/VirtualHost context.)

Also, `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}` is more typical of a directive used in the server config. It is simpler to just use `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` in `.htaccess`.

For this to work in `/members/.htaccess` you would need to change these directives to read something more like the following:

```
# MediaWiki pretty URL rewrites
RewriteRule ^wiki(/.*)?$ wiki/index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ wiki/index.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the really comprehensive answer, I'm still working my way through it. Regarding your comment about the MediaWiki directives not working, they do work (i.e. URL rewriting without the `index.php` does work). Is that unexpected? I took those from the MediaWiki documentation.

Comment: The issue with editing the VirtualHost is that it's a cheap hosting package and I don't have access to those configs.

Comment: "Is that unexpected?" - Well, the first `RewriteRule` that checks against `^/?members/wiki(/.*)?$` could not possibly work if this `.htaccess` file is itself located _inside_ the `/members` subdirectory. However, these requests are probably being handled by the second `RewriteRule` instead (but slightly less efficiently). Whether the second `RewriteRule` works at all is dependent on the system - this is not universal. Do you have a link to the relevant page from the MediaWiki docs - the page I find seems a bit out of date!?

Comment: "The issue with editing the VirtualHost" - I'm not suggesting you should edit the VirtualHost, it's just that the way these directives have been written suggests a _server_ or _virtualhost_ context. If you were writing these specifically for `.htaccess` (or a `<Directory>` container in the server config)  then they would be written differently.